# Make specific column the header in r (reshape/transpose)

Tags: r, reshape, transpose

I am trying to do something quite simple but can't find anything online (and am finding it hard to know what to google).

An example of the dataset I have is as follows.

```
TimeDiff      Speed       Direction
   3            0              0
   2            0             10
  54            0             15 
  36            0             20
```

I want to reshape the dataframe to look like as follows.

```
              0      10      15     20
TimeDiff      3      2       54     36
Speed         0      0       0      0
```

So I basically want to make the direction column my header and timediff and speed my rows.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: the "paste0("", df2["Direction",]) is giving the error "subscript out of bounds"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
setNames(data.frame(t(df)[-ncol(df), ]), as.character(df[, ncol(df)]))
#         0 10 15 20
#TimeDiff 3  2 54 36
#Speed    0  0  0  0
```

This produces a `data.frame` of `int` columns.

```
str(setNames(data.frame(t(df)[-ncol(df), ]), as.character(df[, ncol(df)])))
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ 0 : int  3 0
# $ 10: int  2 0
# $ 15: int  54 0
# $ 20: int  36 0
```

Comment: That's perfect :) Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing but not making the columns factors?

Comment: @Fiona I'm not sure what you mean. The columns are `int` vectors; please see my update. Column names are a `character` vector.